# how can I install python-apt in Dockerfile flask

Tags: python

I want to use the `apt_pkg` module in the python file in my container, but when I add the install code, I can't build a Docker file.

First, the original Docker file is  (*it is work*):

```
FROM ubuntu:xenial
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing
RUN apt-get install -y --fix-missing curl wget zip python-dev python-pip
RUN apt-get install -y build-essential openssh-client tcpdump
RUN pip install requests elasticsearch elasticsearch-dsl virtualenv
RUN cd /opt && virtualenv flask
RUN /opt/flask/bin/pip install flask simplejson requests

EXPOSE 8094

ADD . /opt/
RUN chmod 755 /opt/run.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/run.sh" ]
```

Next, I added this line in DockerFile:

```
RUN /opt/flask/bin/pip install python-apt
```

error:

```
Step 9/13 : RUN /opt/flask/bin/pip install python-apt
 ---> Running in ed421699d0c0
Collecting python-apt
  Downloading python-apt-0.7.8.tar.bz2 (49kB)
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-Mx7WQq/python-apt/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        from DistUtilsExtra.command import *
    ImportError: No module named DistUtilsExtra.command

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-Mx7WQq/python-apt/
The command '/bin/sh -c /opt/flask/bin/pip install python-apt' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

How can I solve this error?

I can't use RUN `apt-get install -y python-apt`, because it can't affect the python file.

> ImportError: No module named apt_pkg

Comment: Why are you using Ubuntu as a base image instead of Python?

Comment: to use the same platform as other containers.

Comment: should I switch to python..?

Comment: I think the python containers are based on debian, which is basically a smaller version of the Ubuntu one. My point is that you shouldn't need to install python yourself

Comment: I tried the base image with python:latest, but I still got the same error.

Comment: Okay, why do you need that package? And why do you need a virtualenv inside a container? You particularly don't need flask or elasticsearch to show a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

So installing `python-apt` in isolated virtualenv fails, because `pip` has outdated version and is not maintained. Just installing the deb package doesn't reflect in virtualenv.

An alternative way is to install working/fixed `python-apt` python package from the other source.

Install `python-apt` in virtualenv. For `Ubuntu Xenial`, the following worked for me:

```
pip install git+https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/python-apt.git@1.1.0_beta5
```

You might want to get appropriate branch for your system from  https://salsa.debian.org/apt-team/python-apt

Also, there might be some pre-reqs to make sure the above build is succeeding:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-distutils-extra libapt-pkg-dev
```

---

See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=845330 for why and https://github.com/excid3/python-apt/issues/2 for more info.